# My jukebox application breaks after cycling through all songs

Tags: javascript

My jukebox application does not start over after going through all the songs in the playlist. Rather it stops functionality all together. So far it plays,pauses,stops,goes back, and next. The second it runs through the final song and I hit "next" nothing happens, nor does any other function work.

```
Jukebox.prototype.next = function() {
  this.jamz[index].pause();
  index++
  this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
  this.jamz[index].play();
  if (index == this.jamz.length) {
    this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
    this.jamz[index].play();
  }
}

Jukebox.prototype.back = function() {
  this.jamz[index].pause();
  index--
  this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
  this.jamz[index].play();
  if (index == 0) {
    this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
    this.jamz[index].play();
  }
}
```

This is the code that runs perfectly until it reaches the end of the final song. I am trying to get it to go back to the first song in my jamz array which has all my music on it.

The error in my console seems to be;

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentTime' of undefined
    at Jukebox.next (script.js:55)

Comment: Check your browser console, I bet it has something to say to you. The highest index in a numeric array is _not_ equal to array.length ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try re-ordering the code to check if you have reached the end of the playlist first - otherwise you'll get a javascript error and it will stop your program ie:

```
Jukebox.prototype.next = function() {
    this.jamz[index].pause();
    if (index == this.jamz.length-1) {
        index=0;
    } else {
        index++;
    }
    this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
    this.jamz[index].play();  
}

Jukebox.prototype.back = function() {
    this.jamz[index].pause();
    if (index == 0) {
        // rotate back from first track to last track
        index = this.jamz.length-1;  
    } else {
        index--;
    }
    this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
    this.jamz[index].play();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check the index if it is not out of the range from 0 to jamz.length - 1 before you call this.jamz[index].play()

Answer (score 0):

Lists in js are 0 indexed, this meanse that the last item in a list has the index `list.length-1`. 
In your case you need to change `index == this.jamz.length` to `index == this.jamz.length-1`. Also, for good mesure, you should never use `==` if you can help it. The `==` operator in js is not the same as the `==` operator in other languages. You want to use the `===` operator.

```
Jukebox.prototype.next = function() {
  this.jamz[index].pause();
  index++
  this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
  this.jamz[index].play();
  if (index === this.jamz.length-1) {
    this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
    this.jamz[index].play();
  }
}

Jukebox.prototype.back = function() {
  this.jamz[index].pause();
  index--
  this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
  this.jamz[index].play();
  if (index === 0) {
    this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
    this.jamz[index].play();
  }
}
```

Comment: In the code above, the back function will produce an error if you are at index 0.

Comment: @MykeBlack That is true, however that wasn't part of OP's question, also SO answers are not meant to debug code.

Answer (score 0):

You are surpassing the length of the array and you aren't setting the next song when it reaches the end of the playlist.

```
Jukebox.prototype.next = function() {
  this.jamz[index].pause();
  this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;

  //Check if you are at the end of your playlist
  if (index === this.jamz.length - 1) {
    index = 0;
  }else{
    index++;
  }
  this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
  this.jamz[index].play();
}
```

Comment: this will not set the currentTime of the track to 0 you need to set the currentTime after you have changed the index to 0 or incremented by 1 if not on the last track.